# apache kafka retention kstream and linked topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a ktable kafka linked to a topic however when retention is done on the topic the messages are also deleted in my ktable And is it possible to keep the values of the Ktable while those of its topic are deleted?

Comment: Have you heard about topic compaction?

Comment: `when retention is done on the topic the messages are also deleted in my ktable` if the topic user retention but not compaction, the data would not be deleted from the ktable automatically -- however, if you loose the ktable, the data is of course gone.

Comment: @cricket_007 No, but I think this is the solution to my problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changelog topics are log compacted with infinite retention time.  At any time, if there is a new event coming up your topic, it will update the state in the KTables for that key.

In your scenario, if you need to make the data available even when source topic is deleted, I will recommend publish the KTable into some output topic to make it more stable.
As KTables are exposed only within the applications and built on top of changelog topics, once your application is gone, you will lose the data unless you use persistent state store.